# How to convert an object from Firestore to an array list?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

When I create a user i have a List with the Urls of the images that that user needs.

Like

```
 final List<String> picturesUrls = pictureUrl;
```

My user object is

```
import java.util.List;

public class User {


    public List<String> picturesUrls;


    public User() {

    }

    public User(List<String> picturesUrls) {

        this.picturesUrls = picturesUrls;


    }

}
```

It all work fine, but when I want to get those data from FireStore

```
  db.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("email",user.getEmail())
                             .get()
                             .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                     if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                         for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()){
                                            Object obj = document.get("picturesUrls");
                                             actualUser = new User(              
                                                     picturesUrls
                                             );
                                         }
                                     }
                                 }
                             });
```

but In the User model, picturesUrls is the type of List and what gives me from FireStore is an object. For now in that list it is only 1 string.
How can I convert that object to a List to create the new User Object and then loop into that List to get the last value ("actual profile picture")

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try this code `List<String> picturesUrls = (List<String>) document.get("picturesUrls");`

Comment: let me try, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you convert `DocumentSnapshot` to instance of `User` class. You would have to initialize getter in `User` class. Then you can use getter to get the url list. 
So you code will be like this :

```java
  db.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("email",user.getEmail())
                             .get()
                             .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                                    for(DocumentSnapshot ds : queryDocumentSnapshots)   {
                                        User user = ds.toObject(User.class);
                                        List<String> urlList = user.getPicturesUrls();
                                    }

                                }
                             });
```